# How to apply input to the set method, and in another case, input outside main?

Tags: java, user-input, setter

me again. This time I need to get user input, plug them into various set methods, and output a value. It sounds pretty easy although the assignment instructions make it seem way harder.

In depth:
I need to declare 4 "Lease" objects in main(), then call a "getData" method thrice. Then I need to return a value for each field in the main(). So to me at least, the obvious next step would be to initialize the field with an input. **However.** I don't think this is possible (hypothetical code):

```
Lease ls = new Lease();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = input.nextLine();
ls.setName(name);
//or 
ls.setName(input.nextLine());
//or
ls.setName() = input.nextLine;
```

I don't think any of these would work, at least not how I used them there. So a more practical way of thinking is needed here.

For context, here is my two programs:

```
class Lease {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    }
    private String name;
    private int aptNumber;
    private double rent;
    private int term;
    private static final int FEE = 10;

    public Lease() {
        name = "XXX";
        aptNumber = 0;
        rent = 1000.0;
        term = 12;
    }

    public void setName(String tenant) {
        name = tenant;
    }

    public void setAptNumber(int apt) {
        aptNumber = apt;
    }

    public void setRent(double monthRent) {
        rent = monthRent;
    }

    public void setTerm(int t) {
        term = t;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAptNumber() {
        return aptNumber;
    }

    public double getRent() {
        return rent;
    }

    public int getTerm() {
        return term;
    }

    public void addPetFee() {
        rent = rent + 10;
        explainPetPolicy();
    }

    public static void explainPetPolicy() {
        String policy = "A pet fee of $10 is added to the monthly rent.";
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class TestLease
{
   public static void main (String args[])
   {
     // Write your code here
     Lease ls = new Lease();
     ls.setName(tenant);
     ls.setAptNumber(apt);
     ls.setRent(monthRent);
     ls.setTerm(t);
    
   }
   public static void showValues(Lease ls)
   {
      System.out.println("\n\nYour lease results:" +
         "\nName      : " + ls.getName() +
         "\nApartment : " + ls.getAptNumber() +
         "\nRent      : " + ls.getRent() +
         "\nTerm      : " + ls.getTerm());
   }
   public static Lease getData(String tenant, int apt, double monthRent, int t)
   {
     // Write your code here
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("Enter lessee name >> ");
     tenant = input.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Enter apartment number >> ");
     apt = input.nextInt();

     System.out.print("Enter rent >> ");
     monthRent = input.nextDouble();

     System.out.print("Enter lease term in months>> ");
     t = input.nextInt();
   }
}
```

This is what I currently have. I'm not sure what to do from here, or even if what I have so far is correct. I feel I'm missing a return statement for getData(), and of course, compiling this gives me "symbol not found" errors.

Even something like `return tenant;` doesn't do much other than make more errors. I would greatly appreciate any help, even just advice

Answer (score 0):

You can set your Lease constructor to take in name, aptnum, rent, and lease as arguments

```
class Lease {
    private String name;
    private int aptNumber;
    private double rent;
    private int term;
    private static final int FEE = 10;

    public Lease(String name, int aptNumber, double rent, int term) {
        this.name = name;
        this.aptNumber = aptNumber;
        this.rent = rent;
        this.term = term;
    }

    public void setName(String tenant) {
        name = tenant;
    }

    public void setAptNumber(int apt) {
        aptNumber = apt;
    }

    public void setRent(double monthRent) {
        rent = monthRent;
    }

    public void setTerm(int t) {
        term = t;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAptNumber() {
        return aptNumber;
    }

    public double getRent() {
        return rent;
    }

    public int getTerm() {
        return term;
    }

    public void addPetFee() {
        rent = rent + 10;
        explainPetPolicy();
    }

    public static void explainPetPolicy() {
        String policy = "A pet fee of $10 is added to the monthly rent.";
    }
}
```

In your main class, when you create the Lease object, input the values into the arguments and then display the Lease with the new values:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static String tenant;
    private static int apt, t;
    private static double monthRent;
    private static Lease ls;
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        getData();
        // Write your code here
        ls.setName(tenant);
        ls.setAptNumber(apt);
        ls.setRent(monthRent);
        ls.setTerm(t);

        showValues(ls);
    }
    public static void showValues(Lease ls)
    {
        System.out.println("\n\nYour lease results:" +
                "\nName      : " + ls.getName() +
                "\nApartment : " + ls.getAptNumber() +
                "\nRent      : " + ls.getRent() +
                "\nTerm      : " + ls.getTerm());
    }
    public static Lease getData()
    {
        // Write your code here
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter lessee name >> ");
        tenant = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter apartment number >> ");
        apt = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter rent >> ");
        monthRent = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter lease term in months>> ");
        t = input.nextInt();

        ls = new Lease(tenant, apt, monthRent, t);
        return ls;
    }
}
```